# Error "request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" in Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just setup a new VPS, and I get this weird error when trying to handle an image that the user uploads that is larger then around 3MB. There's nothing in the logs except:

> request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

So I started digging around and added everything I could find to my Htaccess with no luck. Maybe it's something with my new VPS configuration? I'm new at server management so maybe I missed a module or something? maybe I have to make internal redirects bigger?

I've set up my LAMP stack with VESTA panel which installs apache2 server with back ngnix support.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./wedding.php?w=$1


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks! and happy holidays :)

Comment: It is likely that you have caused a redirect to a URL that will also redirect, in a permanent loop. Does this happen on all URLs? Are you using WordPress? Did you add the `Rewrite` directives outside the `BEGIN`...`END`?

Comment: It happens on my upload php script which is a standard upload, it get stuck on the function: `if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) )`. with no PHP error, only the limit error. I'm using my wordpress and a web app on the same dir on both are working perfect except for this upload script. and it works fine with file up to around 3MB, after that I get this error.

Comment: Did you add the `wedding.php` rewrite directives? What does it do?

Comment: hlafer, I dont think the edit to wordpress is correct, the file that has the error is not part of wordpress it's my php script. Also I handle the rewrite before I pass it on to the wordpress rewrite. And it works on my previous server, I think it's something in apache configuration or maybe a missing module in my VPS

Comment: wedding.php get a "W" post var and shows data accordingly. isn't related to wordpress. it's part of my web app

Comment: Regarding the edit: I've rolled back a bit, but kept the WP tag in, since you _are_ using Wordpress. I think it would be good to have more detail in the question, so please make another edit to explain how your script and Wordpress work together. I would suspect that your Rewrite rules are conflicting with Wordpress's rules, and that you should add a rule to the Wordpress directives to ensure it ignores your script.

Comment: I don't know what a "W post var" is, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: (On a general note, if any of your questions are edited in a way that changes their meaning too much, you are welcome to improve it further - it is after all your question. In this case though I think drawing attention to your use of WP is relevant).

Comment: Got it :) (the general note)

Comment: OMG I found the problem:
`php.ini ->  upload_max_filesize = 2M`
hehehehe Just burned 3 days on being stupid. thanks for your time anyway!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

in the .htaccess prevents infinite looping, by checking an internal variable REDIRECT_STATUS. There is an infinite loop somewhere, or a redirect loop potential enough to slow down your web page drastically. I suggest you comment this line and see what happens. If the redirect loop is infinite, it will error out in browser. If not, the page will load, but will take a good amount of time.

Also I suggest to enable rewrite logs. Adding the following inside your vhost entry in apache config file, and reloading the server would enable rewrite log. That can give a clue, which rewrite log is giving you trouble.

```
    RewriteLog "logs\rewritelog.txt"
    RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: I tried that, this is actually a fix I found that is not working, the script was without this line before and behaves the same. :/

Comment: What is your browser status when you comment this line in .htaccess? Does your browser shows infinite loop detected error? And do you have any other htaccess files in the parent directories? Even an htaccess file residing in '/' itself can alter the expected outcome.

Comment: Exactly the same: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: The browser is returning the error i've set it to return to the user if this line breaks: `if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) )`. the .htaccess is only in the main folder

Comment: I have the log already, just dont understand any of it. Do you want me to upload it here?

Comment: It'd be worth a look, though I cannot guarantee the fix.

Comment: This is the end of it:
`add per-dir prefix: ./wedding.php -> /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/./wedding.php
strip per-dir prefix: /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/./wedding.php -> ./wedding.php
applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri './wedding.php'
strip per-dir prefix: /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/./wedding.php -> ./wedding.php
applying pattern '.' to uri './wedding.php'
/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/ with /
 internal redirect with /./wedding.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/wedding.php -> wedding.php`

Comment: OMG I found the problem:
`php.ini ->  upload_max_filesize = 2M`
hehehehe Just burned 3 days on being stupid. thanks for your time anyway!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was somewhere else entirely!

My php.ini file had a:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

If you have this problem make sure these two values are correct for your needs:

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: That helps, but I'm not sure it is the whole solution: it means that the bug will pop up again if a file is uploaded that exceeds the permitted size. Where this happens it should display an error instead, presumably.

Comment: Yeah I handle it on the upload.php file itself, if the file exceeds 8MB I return an error with maximum file size reached. Thanks